# Why my django m2m_changed signal not triggered?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I am trying to validate an image field which have a m2m relationship with the post model
by using the m2m_changed signal but it is not being triggered at all.
clearly there is something that I am missing but don't know what.

```
   class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ManyToManyField('Files', blank=True)
```

here is my signals.py file

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


    @receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Post.images.through)
    def images_changed(sender, **kwargs):
        print("the images signal changed ran")
```

And I also defined the ready method in my apps.py file.

```
def ready(self):
   import social.signals
```

Comment: Can you share the implementation of your `ready` method?

Comment: @willem Yes, it's done.

Comment: Is the incorrect indentation in signals.py a result of copy-paste? Also, how is the m2m field change triggered in the first place?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadDawoudSheraz True I solved it. It was off the identation which was outside of the class. But now I am facing a same problem with template tags. but this everything is ok but not working.

Comment: You can add a new question with relevant details.